# Mapping over an existing array to grab item 6, in jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery

I am trying to map over the existing array which is captured in:

```
var mobileNavArray = jQuery.makeArray(mobileNavItems);
```

I am trying to grab item 6, which is the last item in the array so I can revert the event.preventDefault.. I can't for the life of me get this to work.

[image: code]

Comment: Please post your code as text in here, not as image.

Comment: I don't think you can just put a 6 into the map call. Is that not supposed to be a callback?

Comment: NB: why using `document.getElementsByClassName` when you use jQuery?

Comment: You should really reference the documentation to understand the proper use of $.map.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/    Also, you can't bind an event handler to an array, which is what $.map will return.

Comment: How does getting element 6 help you revert `event.preventDefault()`? I don't think there's any way to revert that.

Comment: I was using it to grab all of the elements as they have the same classname.. I'm trying to learn but keep getting shot down. Is this incorrect incorporate JS with jQ? If so, how would you go about it?

Comment: @S.McKeon look at trincot's answer, in particular the last two gray blocks.

Comment: @S.McKeon you can mix JS and JQuery but generally there's no reason to do so. The point of JQuery is to make things easier and quicker(or at least more coherent) than in standard JS. Using both randomly in your code sort of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`$.map` is not intended to get one particular value from an array. Secondly, you should not put the name of your variable in quotes, as then it is a string, not your array.

Instead of that `$.map`, do:

```
$(mobileNavArray[6]).on('click', function () {
      // ...etc
```

Better even, would be to use a jQuery selector to replace the call of `getElementsByClassName`, and the next line doing the `makeArray`, like this:

```
var $mobileNavArray = $('.dropdown-toggle');
```

And then the line to pick item 6 from it should become:

```
$mobileNavArray.eq(6).on('click', function () {
      // ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use

```
mobileNavArray[6]
```

For grabbing the 6th-item?